# Strange change in script causes infinite deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, where-clause, deadlock

I've added another `WHERE`-condition in my statement of an application. And then I can see a lot of Deadlocks like `LCK_M_` in my Activity monitor. After this has happened the SQL-Server doesn't really recover according to the users. Even when I kill the affected Windows- and SQL-processes - I need to restart the SQL-Server then it works again.

This is the statement how it works.

```
UPDATE myDocuments
SET StatusLead = 10
WHERE FirmaPubINdex NOT IN
(
    SELECT firmapubINdex FROM CSDokument WHERE dokumenttyp='3' AND ProjPubINdex IN
    (   
    SELECT PubINdex FROM CSProjekt WHERE Projektnummer = '123456'  
    )
)
AND ProjPubINdex IN
    (
    SELECT PubINdex FROM CSProjekt WHERE Projektnummer = '123456'  
    )
AND DokumentTyp = '2'
```

And this is the statement which causes the problem. The only change is in the last row.

```
UPDATE myDocuments
SET StatusLead = 10
WHERE FirmaPubINdex NOT IN
(
    SELECT firmapubINdex FROM CSDokument WHERE dokumenttyp='3' AND ProjPubINdex IN
    (   
    SELECT PubINdex FROM CSProjekt WHERE Projektnummer = '123456'  
    )
)
AND ProjPubINdex IN
    (
    SELECT PubINdex FROM CSProjekt WHERE Projektnummer = '123456'  
    )
AND DokumentTyp = '2'
AND StatusLead <> '18'
```

At the moment I'm a bit confused because another user has tested the script lower a full day and had no problems. Then I tried it with another user and that user caused that problem. Could that change in the script really cause that problem or was it by chance?

Comment: use select with (nolock) on your inner sql statements

Comment: You might also avoid the subquery on PubINdex by joining with firmapubINdex

Comment: >>>LCK_M_<<< it's lock and not DEADLOCK. deadlocks are resolved by server automatically

Comment: >>>SQL-Server doesn't really recover according to the users<<< What do you mean saying "recover"? crash recovery, start-up recovery? recovery after restore???

Comment: I mean the performance of the application. When the locks occur it becomes really slow, 10 min for saving a document. The locks never go away - only with killing the processes. But after that the application is still really slow, slower than before. That's what I mean by "it doesn't recover".